# Matching css margin property in String

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing a regexp in Java where I'm trying to find the bottom-margin in the [css "margin:" shorthand property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) in a String and see if it's negative.
The margin property can be specified with 1, 2, 3 or 4 values, end with *px*, *em* or *%* and the values might be negative and/or start with a dot. Values are separated with one or more white spaces in between. What is tried so far is a regexp like this:

```
//E.g. style may look like "... margin: 10px 2px" or "... margin: -.10em 1em 2em" etc.
public void findMargin(String style)
{
    Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("margin:\\s*(-?\\.?\\d+(?:em|px|%)\\s*){1,4}");
    Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(style);

    while (matcher.find())
    {
      .....
    }
}
```

I have problem to find the extract the bottom-margin property. Anyone have some input on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I wrote to find the bottom-margin from the css margin shorthand property:

```
    Pattern compile1 = Pattern.compile("margin:\\s*((-?\\.?\\d+(?:em|px|%)\\s*){1,4})");
    Matcher matcher1 = compile1.matcher(style);

    if (matcher1.find())
    {
        String[] split = matcher1.group(1).trim().split("\\s+");
        String marginBottom;

        if (split.length < 3)
        {
            marginBottom = split[0];
        } else
        {
            marginBottom = split[2];
        }

        if (marginBottom.contains("-"))
        {
            System.err.println("Bottom margin is negative "  + marginBottom);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd be inclined to get the whole property from a single group and then do a simple string split to get the individual values.

Comment: I'd go with your solution it gets a little bit simpler. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A bit more verbose, but also a bit more readable, perhaps?

```
    // sample input string
    String style = "...margin: -.10px 1px 2px;...";        

    // pre-compile patterns
    Pattern marginPattern = Pattern.compile("margin:([^;]+);");
    Pattern valuePattern = Pattern.compile("([\\-\\.\\d]+)(em|px|%)");

    // first step, find margin property...
    Matcher marginMatcher = marginPattern.matcher(style);
    while (marginMatcher.find()) {
        // second step, extract individual numeric values
        String marginPropertyValue = marginMatcher.group(1).trim();
        Matcher valueMatcher = valuePattern.matcher(marginPropertyValue);
        while (valueMatcher.find()) {
            String number = valueMatcher.group(1);
            String unit = valueMatcher.group(2);
            doSomethingWith(number, unit);
        }
    }
```